# AChartEngine Scroll Area

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

Is there any way to limit the scroll area of AChartEngine? I have a graph of stats for a team where the X-axis represents time and the Y-axis represents score and it doesn't make sense to have negative for either. I'd like to make it so that the farthest that the user can scroll down and to the left would put the origin in the bottom left corner of the screen. I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using setPanLimits() method ..

```
double[] panLimits={0,10,0,50}; // [panMinimumX, panMaximumX, panMinimumY, panMaximumY] 
mRenderer2.setPanLimits(panLimits);
```

where `mRenderer2` is  `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` .

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know what order the numbers are in? Also, is there anyway to set it one way without setting it in the other axes? (I have a lot of data that is constantly being changed and graphed again so I'd prefer not to have to update the limits if possible.)

Comment: If ur data is comming dynamically then u should find max and min for both x and y (write some method ), then use those value for  renderer setting.