# How to scale graph after zoom or movement to full screen? Android achartengine

Tags: android, graph, achartengine, linechart

I'm using achartengine to display a LineChartView. Sometimes the graph needs to be redrawn and I want that the new grah is displayed on the whole screen. As long as the graph was not zoomed or moved, it is not a problem. Just one single click is also not a problem.

If the graph was zoomed or moved, the new graph is not being displayed correctly. The new graph is not displayed wrong, but not the same as before.

I have written an example to demonstrate the problem:

openChart() initializes the graph, add a onClickListener in the setOnClick() method and switch between the two graphs in the change() method. I call the change() method from a menu item, but it does not matter.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GraphicalView graphViewe;
private XYSeries series;
private XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer;
private int[] firstGraph = new int[] { -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2,
        -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
private int[] secondGraph = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

private boolean isFirst = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    openChart();
}

private void openChart() {
    series = new XYSeries("Series");
    for (int i = 0; i < firstGraph.length; i++) {
        series.add(i, firstGraph[i]);
    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    seriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    seriesRenderer.setLineWidth(10);
    multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

    multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

    graphViewe = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset,
            multiRenderer);

    setOnClick();
    chartContainer.addView(graphViewe);

}

private void setOnClick() {

    graphViewe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something on click
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == R.id.action_change) {
        change();
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void change() {
    series.clear();
    if (isFirst) {
        isFirst = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < secondGraph.length; i++) {
            series.add(i, secondGraph[i]);
        }
    } else {
        isFirst = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < firstGraph.length; i++) {
            series.add(i, firstGraph[i]);
        }
    }

    graphViewe.repaint();
}
}
```

Is it possible to display the graph always in the same way? No matter he was moved or zoomed.

Comment: I didn't get can u show some snap what happening ?

Comment: 1.[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img843/513/vsgk.png)
2.[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img35/4892/kic1.png)
3.[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img593/6069/4ukb.png)
4.[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img841/5014/ac2c.png)
5.[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img19/3349/j82b.png)
1 - Start, 2 - than change the graph, 3 - change again (change back), 4 - push one time minus (zoom out) and 5 - change again. The fist graph is displayed correctly (look at the x axis).But, it is possible to start always on the left boarder and to end at the rigth?

Comment: Try using setPanLimits() method ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239371/achartengine-scroll-area/22294048#22294048